# Updating list of object when submit formGroup for update

Tags: angular

I have an array of Person in a service that includes some properties:

```
class Person
{
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  Age,
  get FullName() {return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName}
}
```

I am loading the values of the selected person from the array to my FormGroup using patchvalues but my formGroup doesn't contains all the Person fields but only the FirstName and LastName FormControls.

Therefore, while i am updating the Array of Person with the formGroup.values by using Object.Assign method, the updated Person in the list, loosing the Age and the FullName properties because they are not as part of the formGroup.values object.

I know that i can do the updating manually, property by property but i have big formGroups and i am looking for a way to do it automaticly as much as possible.

Comment: make fullname return the same and add || '' and initialise age at the top, like age=0. That will give default values when you do Object.assign

Comment: @Vega, Could you please explain? it sounds interesting but i didn't understand you clearly.

Comment: why don't you add those properties in your form? I mean, you don't **need** to show them in your template, just store them there.

Comment: @Alex Because i don't want to remember to add a property to the formGroup every time i am updating the model.